# Outer Variable scope is not available inside the javascript function

Tags: javascript, parsing

How to access the outer variable inside the inner javascript function , please check my code below i need to access "index" variable inside app() function .

```
 function validate()
    {

    for (index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {
        var parsedData_1;
        var provider = results[index].get("provider");                          
        var user = results[index].get("user");          
        var addresses = user.get("addresses");

        var address = addresses[1];

        var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Address");
        var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);         
        var data = JSON.stringify(address);     


        var parsedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);            
        query.get(parsedData.objectId, {
        success: function(resultadr) {          

        var res = JSON.stringify(resultadr);
        var parsedData_1 = jQuery.parseJSON(res);   
        var apartment = parsedData_1.apartment;

        apa(apartment);

        },
        error: function(object, error) {            
        alert('error');             

        }
        });         

        function apa(apartment)
        {
        alert(index); [I'm not getting the index value inside this function]
        alert(apartment);

        }

    }

    }
```

Inside the function apa() i need the index count , but im unable to get it , please help how to access the outer value inside the function.

Comment: Why do you need index inside apa? You can't access it the way you have it now.

Comment: I need to create some dynamic ids inside that apa() function , so i need it there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see apa() does not have access to the index variable, so I would put it inside the parameter of the function call, and call apa() like this

```
apa(apartment, index);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work either, as when the `get` returns success, for loop has already finished.

Comment: I need to test it, but I think var i = index;apa(apartment, i); could work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using closures to access the index, thus the lastest value assinged to that variable is accessible in the app function. For example, if results.length equlas 11, index in app function will always be 11.

The soltion is to declare a variable inside the for loop, assign the index value to that variable, and pass the variable to app function.

```
//Create a factory function for the app function
//Outside the for loop.

var createAppFunc = function (i) { 
    return function () { 
        console.log(i); 
    };
};
for (var index = 0, l = results.length; index < l; index++)
{
    var newVar = index;
    var app = createAppFunc(index); //Now, app is a function.
}
```

Good Luck :).

Comment: Now Each time I'm Getting the last count value of index now inside function apa() , how can i pass correct values ? if index count 0 means i need to pass 0 to apa(). Thanks inadvance.

Comment: I notieced that, please wait a miute to edit my answer

Comment: Sorry @Oday it's not working , And i don't want to take app() function outside the loop as i will pass many parameters inside it . Thanks For your response :)

Comment: @ManoharSingh your app function does still in the for loop and stored in the app varilable. What outside the for loop is the factory of the app function. Also I tested the code, and it is working in that the index value is available in all instances of the app function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function.bind()` to pass the actual index as first argument to the sucess-callback. There you can get it and pass it along as parameter to function `apa()`. And: use keyword `var` for the index in `for()`.

```
function validate() {

    for (var index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {

        /* all the vars here */

        query.get(parsedData.objectId, {
            success: function(idx, resultadr) {
                var res = JSON.stringify(resultadr);
                var parsedData_1 = jQuery.parseJSON(res);   
                var apartment = parsedData_1.apartment;
                apa(idx, apartment);
            }.bind(null, index),
            error: function(object, error) {            
               alert('error');             
            }
        });

        function apa(index, apartment) {
            console.log(index); console.log(apartment);
        }

    }
}
```

The first parameter (here: null) of `bind()` sets the `context` of the bound function. Whatever you pass in will be accessible in the success-callback by the keyword `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I think every time you call the function the call will be compromised by next loop call.. so at last the method will be called only once.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare index variable globally then all the functions have access to it